# Spectral representation of a white stationary process

Tags: mathematical-physics, fourier-transform, power, stochastic-processes, signal-processing

I am trying to better understand the spectral representation of stochastic processes. From the book "Spectral Analysis for physical applications" by Walden and Persival:

The spectral representation theorem for discrete parameter stationary processes states: "Let $\{X_t\}$ be a [...] discrete parameter stationary process with zero mean. There exists an orthogonal process, $\{Z(f)\}$, defined on the interval [—1/2,1/2], such that

$$
X_t = \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}e^{i2\pi ft}dZ(f)
$$
"

I was wondering how would $Z(f)$ look for $X_t$ a white process (i.e., the power spectrum density is flat). I came up with the following possibility, and was wondering if this is correct and/or if there are some better/other possibilities as to how $Z$ could look:

$$
Z(-1/2) := 0\\
dZ(f_j) := 1/\sqrt{N} e^{i \phi_j} \quad \text{for} \; f_j = 2 \pi j/(2N),\, j=-N,...,N
$$

with $\phi_j$ uniform random variables on $[-\pi, \pi]$. Then taking the limit for $N\rightarrow \infty$ would give a white process?

(I asked this question in the Mathematics Stack Exchange https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4643346/spectral-representation-of-a-white-stationary-process, without any comment or answer, so thought I'd have more chance here as it's "Math for Physical Application" topic, but open to moderators thoughts)

Comment: Looks like you are interested in the Rice's representation of white noise: Mathematical Analysis of Random Noise by Rice, 1944

Comment: Thank you for that! I'll look into it

Comment: this $\mathbf {Y}_N=\sum_{k=0}^{N}e^{\mathfrak j \phi_k} e^{\mathfrak j k 2\pi/N }$ approaches a white noise process $\mathbf {Y}$ in the limit as $N\to \infty$ meaning that its power density spectrum is constant if the random variates  $\phi_k$ are independent and uniform in $[-\pi,+\pi)$. As a consequence of the central limit theorem it is also a normal (Gaussian) wide-sense stationary process , that is both its first and second order distributions are normal.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that's what I wrote, but with the $1/\sqrt{N}$ factor in front, so that the power doesn't diverge as it would in your case.